# Python cx_Oracle connection error......Attaching the error

Tags: python

Attaching the error that is generated....Someone please help

```
*** Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32. ***
*** Remote Python engine  is active ***
>>> 
*** Remote Interpreter Reinitialized  ***
>>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "J:\CODE\MINI\SignIn.py", line 24, in loginCheck
    con=cx_Oracle.connect('system/oracle@localhost:1521/xe')
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1050: Oracle Client library must be at version 11.2 or higher
Exit code:  0
>>>
```

Comment: Check to make sure you have the correct Oracle instant client installed and insure that you have the correct version 32/64 bit based off your python version installed correctly. I will post an answer for you to try a different connection method in case the above doesn't work. @arun jose

Comment: The error shows you do have a set of Oracle client libraries installed but they are an old version.  Before you run Python you should set PATH so  a version 11.2 or later set of Oracle client libraries occurs before any other Oracle libraries.  These libraries are included in Oracle XE (I'm assuming you have 11.2 XE), so just make sure your PATH entries are in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up the connection via ODBC on windows - again make sure you have the correct Oracle instant client version installed that matches your Oracle installation.

```
import cx_Oracle

def myDbTest():                                
  dsn_odbc = cx_Oracle.makedsn("localhost", 1521, "xe")
  conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user="yourusername", password="yourpassword", dsn=dsn_odbc)
  cursor = conn.cursor()
  query = "select * from whatever" 
  return cursor.execute(query)
```

Comment: My python is 64 bit version, so is 64 bit instant client version compulsory.

Comment: Please provide me with the path of your Oracle client @arunjose

Comment: Your example has nothing to do with ODBC except you've used 'odbc' in a variable name.  It is a cx_Oracle example making cx_Oracle function calls.  And cx_Oracle internally using functionality from the Oracle Call Interface.  This is totally distinct from ODBC which has different functions and functionality.